# SQL LIKE condition working with result from another query

Tags: sql, sql-like

Does something like this work

```
SELECT color
FROM rawdata 
WHERE color LIKE (
    SELECT TOP 1 color_condition 
    FROM rules
    WHERE rules_id=1
)
```

If the color_condition of rule 1 would be `B%` would this return an entry from the rawdata where `color = 'Blue'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

At least in SQL Server it does and it looks like you are using that from the `TOP`

```
WITH rawdata(color) As
(
SELECT 'Blue' UNION ALL SELECT 'Red'
), rules(color_condition,rules_id) AS
(
SELECT 'B%',1
)
SELECT color FROM rawdata 
WHERE color LIKE (SELECT TOP 1 color_condition 
                  FROM rules WHERE rules_id=1)
```

Returns

```
color
-----
Blue
```

Comment: @Cilvic - BTW you can test some adhoc queries like [the one in my answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/94831/) here [http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is "yes" but I wonder if it is your particular SQL construct that is causing your doubt. Personally, I prefer to not see the predicate interrupted with a subquery. See if you find this easier to read:

```
SELECT D1.color 
  FROM rawdata AS D1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM rules AS R1
                WHERE D1.color LIKE R1.color_condition 
                      AND R1.rules_id = 1
              );
```